# Overload operator() and variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, operator-overloading, variadic-templates

I am writing a small Tensor class, that shell take the type and the rank as template parameters:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Tensor {
    size_t rank_ = N;
    size_t size_ = 0; // At this point all dimensions have the same size
    vector<T> data;   // Holds n**N elements in one block of memory 
public:
    Tensor(size_t n);
    template<size_t ...Args>
    T& operator()(Args... args);
};
```

The data is stored in a `std::vector<T>`. For accessing the data, I want to overload `operator()` which must take `N` arguments, where `N` is the rank of the tensor.
My question is, what is "the best" way, to implement `operator()`? Initially, I thought about a `std::initializer_list<size_t>`, but I do not want the caller to be forced to use `({i,j,k,...})`, so I thought about using variadic templates together with fold expressions. However, before actually implementing, I am getting a lot of errors for this function (MSVC):

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
template<size_t ...Args>
T& Tensor<T, N>::operator()(Args... args) {
    static_assert(size_of...(args) == N, "Wrong number of indicies");
    // do actual implementation here;
}
```

e.g.

```
error C2350: 'Tensor<T,N>::operator ()' is not a static member
error C2513: 'Tensor<T,N>::operator ()': no variable declared before '='
error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'args'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Does someone have a hint for me what is going on here or what the best way for implementing `operator()` is? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration of the call operator to

```
template<typename ...Args> //use typename instead of size_t
T& operator()(Args ...args);
```

You can restrict the allowed types either via `enable_if` or one of the concepts (c++20 - requires clause).

Is `size_of` a custom implementation? Maybe you wanted to use the `sizeof...` operator?

```
//the argument to sizeof... is the parameter pack (Args) and not the variable (args)
static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == N, "Wrong number of indicies");
```

References:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Indeed, I am using `sizeof...`, the `size_of...` was just a typo when transferring the code to Stack Overflow. The code is now free of erros and I will now try to do the implementation!

Comment: Remeber the required argument to `sizeof...`, pass the parameter pack. Happy coding.